# How to retrieve 2nd level many to many relationship with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I describe a possible E-R picture here:
Entities are : News, Tag, Magazine

A News belongs to many Magazine (Magazine has many news)
A Tag belongs to many News (News has many tags)

Both are many to many relationships.

Starting from Magazine how would I define models in order to access Tags?

like $magazine->news()->tags(); ?

Answer (score 0):

In model Magazine

```
function news(){
return $this->hasMany(News::class);
}
```

In model News

```
function tags(){
return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
}

function magazine(){
return $this->belongsTo(Magazine::class);
}
```

In model Tag

```
function news(){
return $this->belongsTo(News::class);
}
```

Now

Since magazine has many news it returns a collection

```
@foreach($magazine->news as $n)
    {{ $n->id }}
        @foreach($n->tags as $tag)
            {{ $t->id }}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: this is wrong....for tag i mean....a tag can be applied to many news....so the function tags() belongsToMany(Tag::class)! And in Tag model the function news() belongsToMany(News:class)

Comment: hasMany and belongsTo  are not definitely the correct way... since it's a many to many relationship.